# prolog, how to correctly use escape sequences

Tags: prolog, yap

I need (for design choices) to obtain a list who respects the following pattern:

```
Uses = ['foo\/1', 'foobar\/2'].
```

I'm able to build up the 
    name/number pattern
doing:

```
all((P\/A), (rule(X, Ux, _, Module), member(U, Ux), U = (P/A)), Uses).
```

where rule is an internal fact and Ux is a list.

I can escape slashes easily, using the '/' shortcut, but what about putting (P/A) between quotes?

How do that? please help me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, If you leave off the escape and just use `P/A`, then you'll get something like `Uses = [foo/1, foobar/2]` without the quotes or escapes. But it depends upon what `rule` produces for `Ux`. The elements of `Ux` would need to be `blah/3` format (no quotes or escapes) as well.

Comment: `?- all(P\/A, member(P/A, [x,x/y,y]), L).
L = [x\/y]` I think you should *not* work with atoms (i.e. quoted expressions). What's the purpose of `Uses` ?

Comment: Uses will contain the body of X, which is a predicate.
Because of serialization requirement (JSON) every member of Uses should be compatible with the json TERM, and so putted between quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain `'foo/1'`, you can easily use `atomic_list_concat/2` predicate as follows:

```
Functor=foo,
Arity=1,
atomic_list_concat([Functor, '/', Arity], Output).
```

In this way `Output` variable will be bound to `'foo/1'` term.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them between 3 apexes:

```
?- A=foo, B=1, writeln('''A/B''').
'A/B'
A = foo,
B = 1
```